# Update multiple IDs

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

My goal is a simple code, where I submit a value, which is being updated in to two (or more) ID's. The code I present below is a working (and simple) code but not possible to update to ID's with the value from a form, and as such I know it is not the right code but it is in the (somewhat) right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>

<title>AJAX TEST</title>


<script>
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
 var formID = $( this ).closest('form').attr('name');
 var data = $( this ).serializeArray();
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data) + " -> " + formID);
 $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : '/dev/Ajax2021/parse.dna',
            data        : data,   // our data object
            dataType    : 'text', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            success     : function (data, status)
            {
                $('#' + formID).html(data); //content loads here
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err)
            {
                console.log("error");
            }
 })
 e.preventDefault();
});
</script>

</head>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="_geo_1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="number" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="start">
    <button>Submit 1</button>
</form>

<hr><br>

<div id="_geo_1" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    Text to be replaced with content from the parse.dna file
</div>

<div id="_geo_2" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    Text to be replaced with content from the parse.dna file
</div>

</body>
</html>

parse.dna file

<div id="_geo_1">
    The new content to replace the original ID content
</div>

<div id="_geo_2">
    The new content to replace the original ID content
</div>

<!-- The values from
    <input type="text" name="number" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="start">
    will be a part of this in the next stage. Until then just replacing some static text
-->
```

Comment: Sorry, but i still didn't understood your question .Please elaborate.

Comment: It's not clear, you send a `POST` request and you want to update the fields based on that `POST`? If that's the case you don't need to use the returned `data` from the `success` function.

Comment: There are a number of issues with the code as is. You include jQuery twice, you have two `</body>`  end tags, the first of which should be an opening tag `<body>`. It's not clear what `parse.dna` does.

Comment: Sorry the extra </body> tag. Error from my side and the second query was inside remarks statements (been removed now)

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth: Here is a working snippet that demonstrates how some of your points can be achieved:

```js
$( document ).on("submit", "form", function(e){
 var formID = $( this ).closest('form').attr('name');
 var data = $( this ).serializeArray();
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data) + " -> " + formID);
 $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            //            '/dev/Ajax2021/parse.dna', // the url where we want to POST to
            data        : data,   // our data object
            dataType    : 'text', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
  //        encode      : true,   // not needed here
            success     : function (data, status)
            {
                $('#' + formID).html(data); //content loads here
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err)
            {
                console.log("error");
            }
 })
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="_geo_1" action="">
    <input type="text" name="number" value="123"> <input type="text" name="name" value="start">
    <button>Submit 1</button>
</form>

<hr><br>

<div id="_geo_1" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    Placeholder 1
</div>

<div id="_geo_2" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
    Placeholder 2
</div>
```

I replaced your `<span>` elements with `<div>`s and used another API for the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Hi Carsten. Thanks for the input. I have replaced your code within my original and initial post. I am almost there, but...

When submitting the form, then...

The content from the original id:_geo_1 is being replaced with both id:_geo_1 and id:_geo_2 from the parse.dna file.

The original id:_geo_2 is not being replaced, at all.

The expected result should have been that _geo_1 is being replaced with _geo_1 and _geo_2 with _geo_1...

It seems like it is only replacing the ID's which has the same name as the Form. The Form name should not be involved